# How to get length of char array, so that valgrind is satisfied

Tags: c++, arrays

I have this constructor from my custom string class ( for homework ) that receives char array as parameter. Then each time it receives a char array like this one: "Hello", valgrind reports "Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialized value", but the programme still works correctly. I tried several ways of taking the length and still got this problem. So is there a correct way to get the length of char array like the one I mentioned above, without valgrind having problems with it?

```
CString::CString ( const char * charArray )
{
  index = 0;
  arrAlocated = 0;
  string = nullptr;
  int length = strlen ( charArray );


  for ( index = 0; index < length; ++index )
  {
    if ( index == arrAlocated )
    {
      realloc ( string, index, arrAlocated );
    }
    string [ index ] = charArray [ index ];
  }
  string [ index ] = 0;
}
```

This is the class declaration.

```
class CString
{
public:

  int arrAlocated;
  int index;
  char * string;

      CString ( );

      CString ( const char * array);

      CString ( const CString & other );

      ~CString ( );

      void clear ( );

      CString & operator = ( const CString & other );

      bool operator == ( const CString & other ) const;


      char operator [] ( int i ) const
      {
        return string[ i ];
      }

      void realloc ( char *& string, int index, int & arrAlocated );

      int length ( )
      {
        return strlen ( string );
      }

      friend ostream & operator << ( ostream & os, const CString & o )
      {
        for ( int i = 0; i < o.index; ++i )
        {
          os << o.string [ i ];
        }
        return os;
      }
};
```

And here is my realloc function

```
void CString::realloc ( char *& string, int index, int & arrAlocated )
{
  arrAlocated += 10;
  arrAlocated *= 2;

  char * newArray = new char [ arrAlocated ];

  for ( int i = 0; i < index; ++i )
  {
    newArray [ i ] = string [ i ];
  }
  delete [] string;
  string = newArray;
}
```

Comment: Which conditional jump or move is valgrind reporting on?

Comment: On strlen in the constructor

Comment: Since the problem seems to be in the constructor, you need to show us how you're calling it.  [Edit] the question to include the code where the constructor is invoked, and how all the parameters that are passed to the constructor are constructed and assigned values.

Comment: I just fixed it, looked into the code that invoked the constructor, and I did not append '\0' at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What exactly is your input?

[Source](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strlen/)

> The length of a C string is determined by the terminating null-character: A C string is as long as the number of characters between the beginning of the string and the terminating null character (without including the terminating null character itself).

So if your input is missing trailing null caracter, strlen won't work.

Comment: Lets say that the input is "123456". Then I get the valgrind warning.

Comment: Exactly, your input should be "123456\0". I see that this solved your problem.